# What happened to Peter Kirk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, captain-kirk

In the Star Trek TOS episode "Operation - Annihilate" we find out that James T. Kirk's nephew, Peter is one of the survivors of the Deneva Colony. Both his parents were killed by the parasite creatures so what happens to Peter Kirk? Are there any canon answers to this?

Answer (score 7):

Within canon, the answer is that we don't know his fate. The boy isn't mentioned again.

We do learn from a [deleted portion of the script](http://www.orionpressfanzines.com/articles/operationannihilate.htm) that he returned to the planet to live with an adoptive family rather than moving to Earth.

> INT. BRIDGE – ANGLE – KIRK, PETER
>
> The boy Peter is now bright and well, dressed in a small version of the Enterprise uniform. He is smiling up at Kirk as the Captain lays a hand on his shoulder.
>
> **KIRK:** *You’re sure you don’t want to go back to Earth to live with your grandmother?*
>
> **PETER:** *I’m sure, sir. Dad thought Deneva here is the best place in the whole galaxy.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Well, your father’s partner said he and his wife always wanted a boy.*
>
> **PETER:** (saddened) *They’re not like Mom and Dad... but...*
>
> **KIRK:** (nods) *No one ever is, Petey.* (pats on shoulder) *Run along; they’re waiting for you in the Transporter Room.*

[image]

---

Peter plays a major part in the EU novel [Sarek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarek_(novel)). He's just about to graduate Starfleet Academy and is very excited about the prospect of meeting and working with Sarek. The author was apparently unaware of the deleted scene because they make reference to him growing up on Earth under the care of his grandmother Winona Kirk (or possibly he just changed his mind about living with his father's work partner and his wife)

> He’d first become acquainted with Sarek through the Vulcan’s writings
> and speeches, some of which were mandatory reading at Starfleet
> Academy, where Peter was currently a senior cadet. Then, when he’d
> attended a talk the diplomat gave at the Academy two years ago, Peter
> had found Sarek’s approach to diplomacy so interesting, he’d studied
> the ambassador’s eminent career during his spare time. Having met the
> ambassador’s son many times gave his interest a personal aspect.
>
> It was ironic, really. His uncle, Jim Kirk, had spent years working
> beside Sarek’s son, Captain Spock. If things had worked out right, no
> doubt Spock, whom he’d met many times during his uncle’s sporadic
> visits, would’ve been happy—or the Vulcan equivalent—to have
> introduced Peter to his father. If things had worked out right …
>
> Well, Peter mused, things had worked out well enough for someone who’d
> lost his parents tragically at the age of seven.

Comment: is it worth mentioning the canon Kelvin timeline Peter Kirk? - http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Operation:_Annihilate!,_Part_2

Comment: @NKCampbell - You can post a new answer if you feel like it

Comment: I truly do not :D

Comment: @NKCampbell - Let *your* apathy be a guide to *my* apathy.

Comment: As you believe, so shall you do, so shall you do

Comment: @Valorum - I saw the mentioned deleted scene mentioned on Wikipedia they did not give the dialogue to the scene. Would have made a good story continuation in the way tv shows are made today.